# Reading values in ts() function R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the time series function in R `ts()`. I read in value from a a csv file and I store the information in a variable called `nums` This variable has 329 values, which can be broken down into 47 groups of 7 (47*7 - 329). I was trying to create a `time series object`
by following:

```
x <- ts(num, frequency = 47)
```

However, the values stored in `x` are much different that what is stored in `num`. I have provided values for both `num` and `x`. I want to have the same values in `x`  as in `num`, because I want to forecast ahead using the `ts` function.

```
> nums
  [1] 568   485   360   523   514   370   332   758   580   613   544   568   394  
 [14] 389   841   685   719   647   615   389   367   744   717   778   594   551  
 [27] 354   317   731   721   819   662   581   436   394   779   770   793   763  
 [40] 619   412   427   865   805   952   759   677   429   424   935   805   915  
 [53] 780   685   430   404   797   733   766   747   697   446   334   598   868  
 [66] 888   849   707   458   426   950   806   826   804   730   541   439   1,070
 [79] 770   989   863   737   525   461   982   925   906   877   954   532   522  
 [92] 1,070 918   1,010 786   787   499   410   1,041 863   989   833   783   506  
[105] 496   1,057 1,031 983   897   783   492   428   927   875   913   808   655  
[118] 358   356   740   581   771   722   628   417   442   895   791   854   779  
[131] 767   513   415   916   764   1,259 944   797   561   552   988   982   857  
[144] 289   515   337   403   895   879   702   778   721   515   572   912   873  
[157] 892   847   775   535   565   1,047 933   965   931   795   628   651   1,112
[170] 1,332 1,346 1,486 1,416 1,098 1,179 954   216   530   591   586   488   421  
[183] 444   361   788   680   619   464   451   861   851   801   780   672   486  
[196] 412   1,049 1,132 1,022 905   758   574   516   1,045 1,107 1,177 1,068 1,044
[209] 640   718   755   772   798   817   779   540   463   1,002 970   1,033 992  
[222] 748   527   475   935   853   983   985   880   548   631   996   1,041 1,184
[235] 1,015 905   641   547   1,121 1,255 1,235 1,087 1,046 662   711   1,216 1,370
[248] 1,404 1,233 1,464 973   587   980   1,202 997   1,022 876   552   549   1,018
[261] 966   876   1,139 962   682   685   1,311 1,289 1,220 1,227 1,105 758   667  
[274] 1,258 1,511 1,509 1,462 1,185 834   946   1,149 975   919   949   883   555  
[287] 502   1,055 979   1,048 938   825   519   351   574   983   989   1,116 927  
[300] 707   588   1,111 1,042 1,096 1,034 860   600   528   1,052 1,019 1,036 1,154
[313] 1,043 740   570   1,042 990   1,149 1,063 895   579   503   1,103 1,073 1,081
[326] 1,017 882   632   602  


> x
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(7, 47) 
Frequency = 47 
  [1] 141 108  78 123 118  81  71 192 146 156 132 141  83  82 225 173 180 164 157  82
 [21]  80 188 178 202 152 136  75  70 184 181 220 167 147  97  83 203 198 210 194 158
 [41]  87  93 235 216 267 193 170  95  91 261 216 253 204 173  96  85 212 185 196 189
 [61] 174 101  72 153 236 245 227 176 103  92 266 217 222 215 183 131  98  26 198 281
 [81] 234 186 124 104 277 257 250 240 268 128 122  26 255   2 206 207 113  86  12 234
[101] 281 223 205 116 112  23   8 278 248 205 111  94 258 238 252 218 166  77  76 187
[121] 147 199 182 159  89  99 247 209 230 203 197 117  88 254 195  55 263 212 139 137
[141] 280 277 231  69 119  73  84 247 241 175 202 181 119 143 251 237 246 226 201 129
[161] 140  18 260 270 259 211 159 165  36  58  59  65  62  31  44 268  68 127 151 148
[181] 110  90 100  79 208 171 158 106 102 233 228 214 204 169 109  87  20  39   7 249
[201] 192 144 120  16  34  43  25  15 162 179 191 200 213 219 203 130 105   1 272   9
[221] 283 190 125 107 261 229 278 279 242 134 160 284  12  45   3 249 163 133  38  53
[241]  52  29  17 167 177  48  60  61  51  64 273 149 276  47 285   7 239 137 135   5
[261] 271 239  40 269 172 173  57  56  49  50  33 192 168  54  67  66  63  46 224 264
[281]  41 274 256 265 244 138 114  22 275  19 262 221 121  74 144 278 281  37 258 176
[301] 150  35  13  30  10 232 154 126  21   6  11  42  14 187 142  13 282  41  24 247
[321] 145 115  32  27  28   4 243 161 155
attr(,"levels")
  [1] 1,002 1,010 1,015 1,017 1,018 1,019 1,022 1,031 1,033 1,034 1,036 1,041 1,042
 [14] 1,043 1,044 1,045 1,046 1,047 1,048 1,049 1,052 1,055 1,057 1,063 1,068 1,070
 [27] 1,073 1,081 1,087 1,096 1,098 1,103 1,105 1,107 1,111 1,112 1,116 1,121 1,132
 [40] 1,139 1,149 1,154 1,177 1,179 1,184 1,185 1,202 1,216 1,220 1,227 1,233 1,235
 [53] 1,255 1,258 1,259 1,289 1,311 1,332 1,346 1,370 1,404 1,416 1,462 1,464 1,486
 [66] 1,509 1,511   216   289   317   332   334   337   351   354   356   358   360
 [79]   361   367   370   389   394   403   404   410   412   415   417   421   424
 [92]   426   427   428   429   430   436   439   442   444   446   451   458   461
[105]   463   464   475   485   486   488   492   496   499   502   503   506   513
[118]   514   515   516   519   522   523   525   527   528   530   532   535   540
[131]   541   544   547   548   549   551   552   555   561   565   568   570   572
[144]   574   579   580   581   586   587   588   591   594   598   600   602   613
[157]   615   619   628   631   632   640   641   647   651   655   662   667   672
[170]   677   680   682   685   697   702   707   711   717   718   719   721   722
[183]   730   731   733   737   740   744   747   748   755   758   759   763   764
[196]   766   767   770   771   772   775   778   779   780   783   786   787   788
[209]   791   793   795   797   798   801   804   805   806   808   817   819   825
[222]   826   833   834   841   847   849   851   853   854   857   860   861   863
[235]   865   868   873   875   876   877   879   880   882   883   888   892   895
[248]   897   905   906   912   913   915   916   918   919   925   927   931   933
[261]   935   938   944   946   949   950   952   954   962   965   966   970   973
[274]   975   979   980   982   983   985   988   989   990   992   996   997
```

Comment: `nums` doesn't look like a numeric (the decimal separator should be `.`). Maybe you should use `read.csv2` to read your data? Please provide the output of `dput(nums)`.

Comment: Won't work with those `,`. You'd need to clean up with `gsub` first. Much better to read the data correctly in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have commas in your numbers. You need to do a conversion with `as.numeric` after removing the commas:

```
num <- gsub(",", "", nums) #Get rid of commas AND factor to character conversion
num <- as.numeric(nums) #character to numeric conversion
```

Comment: Why do I need `as.character()`?

Comment: Normally you need `as.character` to convert a factor to numeric (since they have stored integer codes), but apparently `gsub` actually does that automatically (edited).

Comment: @MaxKim I can only reiterate, fix the file reading function to read in the data correctly and such a clean-up step becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @Roland doesn't `read.csv2` read commas in as decimal places though?

Comment: @Roland No I think here you can't here avoid manual conversion( clean-up).

Comment: `read.csv2` is a convenience function to read in data from files that follow the conventions used in Germany and other European countries. I'd assumed that was the case here, but it seems it's not.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
  ts(as.numeric(gsub(',','.',num,fixed=TRUE)),frequency = 47)
```